# How can I combine two json lists into one data frame?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, data-science

this is the problem:

```
    dic1=json.loads(info1)
    dic2=json.loads(info2)
    df=pd.json_normalize(dic1)
    print(df)
```

I want both dic1 and dic2 in one data frame in a understandable format.

Comment: Why you don't read them using the `read_json()` function from pandas and the merge them using the `merge()` function from pandas?

Comment: Please add some details on your JSON data and why your code does not work. What is your input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**code**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# dummy JSON
json_ =  '{ "name":"A", "age":30, "city":"NY"}'
json__ =  '{ "name":"B", "age":20, "city":"LA"}'

# create dataframe
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([json.loads(json_)]),
                pd.DataFrame([json.loads(json__)])]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**output**

```
df
Out[01]: 
  name  age city
0    A   30   NY
1    B   20   LA
```